# Create a nice page with logo's in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a nice page with logo's the logo's have different sizes. The logos need to be five in a row and must be showing responsive.

Till now I have set up this page: https://deduik.com/werkgevers-referenties.html

If this page is viewed on iPhone some of the logos will overlap others. The logos must have some white space around them and center on horizontal line so it looks nice.

**Question** how can i setup this page the best way in Bootstrap?

I now am using:

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 40px!important;
    }
.row{
    margin-bottom: 35px !important;
}
ul {
/*  padding:0 0 0 0!important;  */
    margin-top: 20px!important;
    margin-bottom: 220px!important;
/*  margin:0 0 0 0!important;  */
}
ul li {
  list-style:none!important;
        margin-top: 20px!important;
    margin-bottom: 20px!important;
}
ul li img {
    max-width: 95%;
    position: relative!important; 
    top: 50%!important;
    transform: translateY(-50%)!important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/philips.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/uwv.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/de-lage-landen.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/rabobank.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/roc-amsterdam.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
   <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/fontys-hogescholen.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/start-people.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/TNO.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/anb-amro.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/de-bijenkorf.png" class="img-responsive"></li>   
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
      <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/asml_logo.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/politie.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/brandweer-brabant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/kpmg.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ministerie_van_justitie_logo.png" class="img-responsive"></li>   
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
     <ul class="row">
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/Bedrijfs-logo-daf.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ing-bank.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/logo-cz.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/logo_enexis.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/hogeschool_arnhem_en_nijmegen.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
     <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
      <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/continu.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/shell.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/nxp-eindhoven.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ministerie-economische-zaken.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-amsterdam.png" class="img-responsive"></li>    
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
         <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/fokker_wlmo_logo.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/zwitser-leven.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/university_of_amsterdam.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/apg_logo.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/dordrecht.png" class="img-responsive"></li>   
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/prorail-utrecht.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ericsson.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/provincie-noord-brabant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/c1000-supermarkten.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/twentse-zorg-centra.png" class="img-responsive"></li>    
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
   <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/asr-vastgoed.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/vitalis.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/waterschap-de-dommel.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/alliantie.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/MMC.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>  
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
  <ul class="row">
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-weert.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/brabant-wonen.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/schiphol-amsterdam.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/clariant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-eindhoven.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>   
   <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
   <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/bavaria-lieshout.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/plantyn_logo.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/de-bascule.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/fme.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/carglass.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
     <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
   <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/frencken-eindhoven.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-acht-karspelen.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/staatsbosbeheer.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-bergen-op-zoom-brabant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-dronten.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/wolters_bv.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/diamant_groep.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/hww_zorg.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/van-hoorn.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/feder_advocaten.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-roerdalen.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-westvoorne.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-zwartewaterland.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/grafisch-lyceum-rotterdam.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gx-nijmegen.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
   <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/summa-collega-brabant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/mik-kinderopvang.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/sanoma.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/prodas-asten.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/radar-arbeidsdeskundig-bureau.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
   <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/roc-friese-poort.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/siza.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/spaarne-landen.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/spie.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/veiligheids-huis-friesland.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/vencotec.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/vesteda.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/sioux-eindhoven.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/wvs-groep.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/blok-group.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/agio.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/career-consultancy.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/dierenkliniek-de-kempen-eersel.png"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/every-angle.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/extrema.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ggz-oost-brabant.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/paccar-financial.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/provincie-gelderland.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/spies-spreken-nijmegen.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/umc-radboud-training-persoonlijke-ontwikkeling.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/van-lanschot.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/summa-collega-brabant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/van-hoorn.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/blok-group.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/edco-eindhoven.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ergon-eindhoven.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-hoogeveen.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/langeland_logo.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/pink-rabbit.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/cross-marks.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-deurne.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/brinck-groep-zeewolde.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/divetro.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/doesburg-components.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gastouder-bureau-roodkapje.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/inno_metaal.gif" class="img-responsive"></li> 
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/sta-op-training-advies.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gemeente-waalre.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/logo_Kentalis.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gymnasium-montfort.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/hamelink-tooren.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/lengersdorf.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/lunet-zorg-eindhoven.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/nts-group.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/nationale-postcode-loterij.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
    <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/renault-hapert-brabant.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/rsg-finance.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/schipper.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/koninklijke-de-vries-scheepsbouw-bv-aalsmeer-1243.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/sophianum.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="row">
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/hoppeLogo.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/napoleon.gif" class="img-responsive"></li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/Xycarbx_ceramics.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/Gemeente-westvoorne-logo.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/scannexus.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li> 
      <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="row">
       <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/gilissen.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ons.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/jonk.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/MB-logo.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/boboli.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li> 
      <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="row">
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/MS-schippers-logo.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/artemis.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/licht-reclame.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/ah_dairy.jpeg" class="img-responsive"></li>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/woonzorg-nederland.png" class="img-responsive"></li>
       <li class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-mg-block visible-sm-block visible-sm-block"></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Or do i have to set this up like this?

Comment: <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/philips.jpg" class="thumbnail"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/uwv.jpg" class="thumbnail"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img src="https://deduik.com/logo/de-lage-landen.png" class="thumbnail"></div></div></div>

Comment: You should use @media-query to define different margins/padding

Answer (score 1):

You can add media queries to differentiate your device sizes. Like this,

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
{ *your styles for this size here}
```

You can add as much as media queries you need, depending on device size you wish your website to display on.

Hope this is the answer you looking for.